# Open continuous form Access in new records

Tags: vba, ms-access

I use MS Access 2019 to build a single form to add new items details.
I tried to add another sub form with continuous view. I tried to find a way so the continuous from opens a new record only, but failed. It opens all previous records. The two forms have no relationship but the data on the continuous form and the form will be added in another table.

These did not work:

```vb
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
```

```vb
DoCmd.OpenForm FormName:="Form1", DataMode:=acFormAdd
```

Comment: Instead of VBA, try setting form DataEntry property to Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `Data Entry` property to `Yes` in the `Data` tab.

[image: MS Access]